# Socket Exception : No route to host

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

Can anyone tells me why an IPhone 11 blocks a Unity application from using Wi-Fi Network while trying to connect to a device over Internet ? while another IPhone 7 with the same ios version and the same Unity application doesn't do this !!

I'm using C# System.Net.Sockets function to make a TCP Client application, it works very well in Unity simulator and also in Android devices, this problem just happens with my IPhone 11.

Checked all the Firewall and restrictions and everything seems to be the same, but still getting the same error : SocketException: No route to host

here is the function I use :

```
    public string IP = "192.168.1.80"; // or a public IP that forwards the request to the specified Local IP via the chosen Port
    public Int32 Port = 5000;
    byte[] SendBuf;
    byte[] RecBuf;
    int i;
    TcpClient TcpClient1;
    NetworkStream serverStream;
    Stopwatch Time = new Stopwatch();

     public Int16 MyFunction(UInt16 A, UInt16 data)
    {
        Int16 RetVal = 0;
        TcpClient1 = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        TcpClient1.Connect(IP, Port);

        // here I write my code ...
        serverStream.Close();
        TcpClient1.Close();
        Time.Stop();
        return RetVal;
    }
```

Comment: I think you must give some rights for your app.

Comment: @BASKA OK, but how ?

Comment: You say you want to connect to a "device over the Internet", but 192.168.x.x is a non-routanlw network so it must be on the same wifi as the device.  Is this the case?  The response indicates that the device doesn't have a route to 192.168.1.80, so it is not on that IP network.

Comment: The application can access the device through the local network -like the IP I am assigning here- or by giving the application the Public IP of the device and make a port forwarding on the specified port to reach the specified IP address.
The problem isn't here as I said, but in some IPhones it works while in the others it doesn't !

Comment: Check the connectivity of those devices then; No route to host means exactly that; an ICMP unreachable message was received or the device was unable to find a candidate route in its routing table.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments 
@Paulw11 I've checked it several times for the server device and it is all OK, but for the client I can't find any settings in the IPhone that is related to it, I can't find it in the application list in the settings, also sometimes it appear in the local network list and sometimes it doesn't !! so ??

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you connect your mobile via different network than your PC. Different networks can have different firewall rules.

PC is typically connected via internal network (typically Ethernet). While mobile phones are usually connected via WIFI with stronger firewall rules.